# MVC5 custom HandleErrorAttribute needs to detect whether to return partial view to ajax call

Tags: ajax, exception, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, jsonresult

I've created a custom HandleErrorAttribute in order to implement logging as part of the exception handling.  However, unrelated to the logging, I have run into an issue where I need to render a partialview on an Ajax request instead of a JsonResult.  I can detect that it is an ajax request but I can't figure out how to determine when it is appropriate to generate a JsonResult or a PartialView.  In most instances, a JsonResult is appropriate but in some cases a PartialView is appropriate.  Is there a way to determine what the action is expecting from within OnException()?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find a way to detect the required type of response via a property in filterContext or something that would allow me to dynamically determine the expected response type.  In all of my research, I could not find anything that would make that possible.  So, I dealt with the situation by adding a bool property (defaulting to false) to the custom HandleErrorAttribute class.  I then applied this attribute to the method that is responding with a partialView instead of a JsonResult, setting the property value to true.  When the property value is true, the OnException() method responds with a partialView instead of a JsonResult.

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following snippets could help you detect the required type of response

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    //Determine the return type of the action
    string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
    var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);
    var returnType = method.ReturnType;

    if (returnType.Equals(typeof(JsonResult)))
    {
    }
}
```